# PHP array refactoring

Tags: php, arrays

I'm banging my head against what I am sure is a simple fix to re-structure an array. I don't have any choice over how the array is given to me:

```
Array
(
    [author] => Array
        (
            [0] => John Doe
        )

    [journal] => Array
        (
            [0] => Biology
        )
)
```

But I need the following:

```
Array
(
    [author] => John Doe
    [journal] => Biology
)
```

I've been working on various routes, but my brain doesn't work like this right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value[0];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function reduce_array($array) {
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $new[$key] = $value[0];
    }
    return $new;
}

?>
```

Comment: Nice -- but getting "unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW" error in the foreach loop... :P